# Xamarin Forms binding Swift and Android libs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have need to create C# bindings for Swift and Android libs. I am looking for a tutorial on doing same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Android**

Binding Java libraries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/.

Binding Kotlin libraries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-kotlin-library/

---

**For iOS**

Binding Objective-C libraries : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/

Binding Swift libraries : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/

Comment: Please refer to the detailed steps in those Walkthroughs .